# most optimal ZFS dataset configuration for duplicity back-end

Tags: freebsd, zfs, freenas, incremental-backup, duplicity

I am currently using a FreeNAS system to back up my laptop and desktop. I am using deja-dup (which is a wrapper around duplicity) to handle the client side. Assuming i'm using the out-of-the box defaults on the client, how should I set up my ZFS dataset?

My options are:

- Compression Level: [ none, lz4, gzip[1-9], zle ]
- Mount Options: [ atime, noatime ]
- Record Size: [ 512b, 1k, 2k, 4k..1024k ]
- ZFS Deduplication: [ on, off ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Always use compression (prefer lz4), because it is faster and saves space. Even if you have uncompressable data, you will experience no downsides.
- Record size depends on your data and on your hardware. The downside of a "wrong" (unsuitable) value is lower performance and/or wasted storage.
- Never use deduplication if you don't know the downsides and have a very good reason for it (and the hardware to back it up). In your case, as you already have deduplication by software, it would also give you almost no benefit.

In general the ZFS defaults are sensible. You should change them only if you need them (after testing that you do, not assuming you do). `zdb` can give you some hints as to wether settings like deduplication or compression would do anything, I think it is in the manpage.